# How to display object values in text fields during on dropdown item selection

Tags: ajax, jsf, object, selectonemenu

The dropdown:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{build.approvedRecons}" for="reconSearchFunctionalAreaID"></h:outputLabel>
    <p:selectOneMenu style="width:200px;" id="reconSearchFunctionalAreaID" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="-Select One-" itemLabel="-Select One-" />
         <f:selectItems value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconItemList}"/>
          <p:ajax update="@form" listener="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconDetailsDisplay}" event="onChange"></p:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>............<h:outputLabel for="reconNameID" value="#{build.appvReconName}" />
                 <h:outputText value="#{build.colon}" />
                 <h:outputText value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconCtxVO.reconID}" id="reconNameID" />
```

The listener:

```
public void reconDetailsDisplay(SelectEvent event){

    ReconContextVO tempReconContextVO = ((ReconContextVO) event.getObject());
    ReconContextVO reconCtxVO1 = new ReconContextVO(); 
    reconCtxVO1.setReconID(tempReconContextVO.getReconID());
    reconCtxVO1.setReconName(tempReconContextVO.getReconName());
    reconCtxVO1.setTxnProcessingType(tempReconContextVO.getTxnProcessingType());
    reconCtxVO1.setTxnProcessingType(tempReconContextVO.getTxnProcessingType());
    this.setReconCtxVO(reconCtxVO1);
}
```

`reconItemList` is of type  `List<ReconContextVO>`. In my bean I converted `reconsList` to `reconItemList`. `ReconContextVO` contains

```
private String reconName; 
private String txnProcessingType; 
private String txnProcessingLevel; 
// and their setter & getters
```

Now I would like to display `reconName`, `txnProcessingType`, `txnProcessingLevel` in text fields on change of the dropdown. I wrote the ajax listner method like above code. I din't get any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete problem is caused by incorrect usage of `<p:ajax>`. The `event="onChange"` is invalid. It should be `event="change"` (which is the default already and thus can safely be omitted). The listener method argument is also invalid, it should be `AjaxBehaviorEvent`.

But, after all, you don't need a listener method for this. You can just bind the `<p:selectOneMenu value>` directly to a bean property.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconCtxVO}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="-Select One-" itemLabel="-Select One-" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconItemList}" />
    <p:ajax update="reconDetails" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="reconDetails">
    <h:outputText value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconCtxVO.reconID}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconCtxVO.reconName}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconCtxVO.txtProcessingType}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{approvedReconDetailsBean.reconCtxVO.txnProcessingLevel}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that I assume that you've already a `Converter` for the object and that its `equals()` is properly implemented. You should get conversion/validation error on that if not properly done.